# Chrome V8 sample complie error, how can I solve ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’?

Tags: c++, v8

I am trying running samples with:

```
g++ -I. -Iinclude samples/hello-world.cc -o hello_world -lv8_monolith -Lout.gn/x64.release/obj/ -lrt -ldl -pthread -std=c++0x -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS
```

But I got errors:

```
In file included from ./include/v8.h:30:0,
                 from samples/hello-world.cc:10:
./include/v8-internal.h: In function ‘void v8::internal::PerformCastCheck(T*)’:
./include/v8-internal.h:452:33: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’
             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
                                 ^
./include/v8-internal.h:452:33: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’
./include/v8-internal.h:452:50: error: template argument 2 is invalid
             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
                                                  ^
./include/v8-internal.h:452:61: error: ‘::Perform’ has not been declared
             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
```

I really want to use V8 engine, but I can not even compile a sample.
I wish I could get your help.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Based on your use of `-std=c++0x` instead of `-std=c++11`, one possibility that occurs to me is that perhaps you're using a compiler old enough that it doesn't implement these. No guarantee, but a distant possibility.

Comment: @JerryCoffin identified the problem. `remove_cv_t` was added in C++14, so you'll need to change the standard you're building with.

Answer (score 7):

`-std=c++14` should fix it.

(The official documentation is, unfortunately, outdated in this tiny yet important detail.)